# How to receive real time logs from PID's in terminal?

Tags: python, pid, ray, psutil

I have a computational program written in Python using Ray package with the following output:

```
 Actor(Play001,69a6825d641b461327313d1c01000000)
```

This process uses the following pid:

```
pid = 87972
```

In the Ray dashboard I can view the logs. Snippets is as follows:

```
Logs

192.168.0.101 (PID: 87972)

1 Function 1: Starting up
2 Worker 1: Done
3 Press enter to continue or to exit
```

In Python I managed to check if this PID exists:

```
import psutil
pid = 87972
if psutil.pid_exists(pid):
    print("a process with pid %d exists" % pid)
```

What I want is in real time to display the logs as well in my terminal output. How do I do this?

Comment: Would you like to see the logs remotely, or on the same machine? Also, could you provide your code? It will be easier to help you. See [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: On the same machine; I've posted a solution. If you got one better please post it.

Comment: Are you launching your script from the command line? If so, you could just use a pipe to input the stdout of your script somewhere else

Comment: That is indeed the case

Answer (score 1):

On ray, the driver process outputs on its stdout logs from all other workers. If you want to process your scripts logs on another script, you can use a pipe.

Let's say you have two files: `myrayscript.py` and `mylogparser.py`

On `myrayscript.py` you have your script, just as it was written before.

On `mylogparser` you will receive from stdin ray logs:

```py
while True:
  logLine = input()
  # do your stuff here
```

Now, to use a pipe, from the command line:

```sh
python3 myrayscript.py | python3 mylogparser.py
```

Comment: The code hangs. When pressing ctrl+c:  KeyboardInterrupt
Exception ignored in: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='utf-8'>
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

Answer (score 0):

The following solution works although cumbersome:

```
pid = 87972
p = psutil.Process(pid)   
temp = p.open_files()
sPth = temp[0][0]
oFile = open(sPth)
Content = oFile.read()
msContent = Content.splitlines()
```

For a bit more completeness you can watch for changes in the file.

```
from watchgod import watch
for changes in watch(sPth):
       print(changes)
```